# Django won't resolve path to static file inside VS Code editor

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

The {% load static %} tag at the top of my html file  seems to work

But when I try to link my css file from static folder using this code :

```
{% load static %}

<link href="{% static 'static/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

vscode tries to create a file called {% static 'static/style.css' %} inside my templates directory, meaning  the static keyword isn't being recognized.

Any help in figuring out why would be highly appreciated (screenshot of path at bottom)

Here's my relevant settings.py to link static files

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
     '/Google_Solutions/static/',
    ]
```

My static and templates are in the main directory

and here's my home.html file head where i'm trying to include files

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title> Homepage </title> 



<!-- Template Main CSS File -->
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
```

here's my layout.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static '/favicon-16x16.png'%}">
              
              <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

              <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
              <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
              <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
              <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    {% block head %}

    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: `screenshot of the path` please don't post **screenshots of text**, use text.

Comment: `link href="assets/vendor` - why are these files linked not via `static` template tag? `it tries to create a file` - totally unclear. Elaborate please what this means. Who tries to "create files", where, how. A new file on hard drive?

Comment: `href='{%static "/manifest.json" %}'` - fix spelling of template tags, add space between % and `static`, unify usage of single and double quotes, remove unnecessary leading slash.

Comment: Again i'd like to emphasize i'm only focussing on the static folder that is the first link

Comment: So where are your static files? Inside `static/style.css`, `css/style.css` or in the root of static folder like `styles.min.css`?

Comment: static/styles.css 
i.e. it is in the static directory of my main project folder.
I'll edit my code to reflect that accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out the error , it was only my local vscode

Even if the hover link shows the wrong address, as long as your syntax is correct, your static files will load just fine. Check it by starting your server